# Добавление ключа в реестр через python

Tags: python, реестр, regedit, winreg

Нужно сделать так чтобы питон мог отключать `WinDefender` при помощи реестра.
Надо чтобы по определённому пути был создан ключ DWORD32 и в него записано значение "1"

```py
import winreg

Disable = r'Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\DisableAntiSpyware'

key = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, Disable)
winreg.SetValueEx(key, "DisableAntiSpyware", 0, winreg.REG_DWORD,"1")
key.Close()
```

Код не работает, выдаёт ошибку о том что используется неверный тип данных, но так и не могу понять как это исправить

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки прямо в вопросе.

Comment: А зачем его отключать?

Comment: иногда он мешается и срабатывает ложно, чтоб не копаться в настройках я решил написать два скрипта на питоне, один отключает, а другой включает и получился вот такой переключатель

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`winreg.REG_DWORD` [говорит о том](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#value-types), что записываться будет число, а там вместо числа строка. Поэтому или `"1"` заменить на `1` или вместо `winreg.REG_DWORD` использовать `winreg.REG_SZ`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, заметил ошибку, исправил, теперь всё работает должным образом